# SQLALchemy: Where does the attribute error after data import come from?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, orm

I wrote an application using SQLAlchemy's object relational mapper to store and access data from an SQLite3 database.

- I can call `add_user`to add one or multiple users and call `get_users` to get them
- I can import data from excel and get them with `get_users`
- I can import data from excel and add a user with `add_user`
- BUT I can't get the users with the `get_users` function afterwards, because I'm getting the following error for the entry created with `add_user`: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a simple version of the application:

orm_test.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def orm_setup():
    Base = declarative_base()    
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:main:', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return Base, engine, session
```

orm_test_class.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from orm_test import orm_setup

Base = orm_setup()[0]
engine = orm_setup()[1]

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column('username', String, unique=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

orm_test_functions.py

```
from orm_test_class import User
from orm_test import orm_setup

session = orm_setup()[2]

def add_user(name):
    u = User()
    user_name = str(name)
    u.username = user_name
    session.add(u)
    session.commit()

def get_users():
    users = session.query(User).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user.id, user.username)
    session.close()
```

main.py

```
import fire
from orm_test_functions import add_user, get_users

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire()
```

data_import.py

```
import fire
import pandas as pd
from orm_test import orm_setup

# import engine from orm
engine = orm_setup()[1]

def data_import():
    file = 'Data.xlsx'
    df_user = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'User')
    df_user.to_sql('person', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)


# Command line interface
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire()
```

Comment: Yes. I can also return them using the get_users functions which includes the ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `df_to_sql` drops the original table, which has a primary key defined, and replaces it with a table that does *not* define a primary key.

From the [dataframe_to_sql docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)

> replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.

You can get around this by setting `if_exists='append'` instead of `if_exists='replace'`.

```
df_user.to_sql('person', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

If necessary you can emulate the "replace" behaviour by deleting any existing records from the table before importing the data.

---

This is the code I used to reproduce and resolve:

```py
import io
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
import pandas as pd

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = sa.Column('username', sa.String, unique=True)


engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True, future=False)
# Drop all is redundant for in-memory db
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
sessionmaker = orm.sessionmaker(engine)


def add_user(name):
    session = sessionmaker()
    u = User()
    user_name = str(name)
    u.username = user_name
    session.add(u)
    session.commit()


def get_users():
    session = sessionmaker()
    users = session.query(User).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user.id, user.username)
    print()
    session.close()


DATA = """\
id,username
1,Alice
2,Bob
"""

buf = io.StringIO(DATA)
df_user = pd.read_csv(buf)
df_user.to_sql('person', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)


users = get_users()
add_user('Carol')
users = get_users()

engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs, when I import the data, add a new user and try to get them again. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: You may need to recreate the original table.

Comment: I deleted the db and tried everything from scratch again. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've added the code I used - it reproduces the error with ''replace' but not with 'append'.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the column `id` with `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#using-the-autoincrement-keyword

Comment: I also had something like that in mind, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem and still raises the same error.

Comment: `primary_key=True` is enough to get the auto-incrementing behaviour in SQLAlchemy - that link is about making sure it appears in the DDL, which might be relevant if the table were to receive inserts from other applications.

Comment: I also thought about adding the id column to the `add_user` function. But when I set the value to 0, sqlite won't change it (automatically increment) it anymore, which I would need. Is there a way to enter an 'emtpy' value that sqlite will automatically change? Also, when I create new users with the `add_user` function not having the id and try to get them with `get_users`, the autoincrement works. It just stops working after the data import. Maybe the problem is, that `add_user` addds an object (with id attribute) which represents a db entry, whereas the data from the excel aren't objects.